# When set value to the tablecell's elements, it will crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I want a tableview to show my car's status, it only have 7 cells. And the value is get through the network.When I get the value, and set the cell's label text, it will crash.

#### This is my Table View Controller code

```
@interface CarStatusController ()

@end

@implementation CarStatusController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //init the data
        _carStatuKey = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Total_Km",@"Remain_L",@"Battery_V",@"Tyre_P",@"Cost_L",@"Door",@"Cover", nil];
        _carStatuValue = [NSMutableArray new];
        _resultData = [NSMutableData new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CarStatuCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CarStatuCell"];
    [self postData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)postData {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@DeviceInfo/GetVehicleStatus",API_PREFIX ]];
    NSDictionary *parametersDic = @{@"VehicleID":@"10000"};
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//    [[UserLogin sharedInstance] LoginRequest];
    NSString *token = [[UserLogin sharedInstance] getToken];
    [request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaron-clark-aic-%@",token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Expect"];
    [request addValue:@"Mobile" forHTTPHeaderField:@"DeviceType"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parametersDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    [self ParseData:data];
}

- (void)ParseData: (NSData *)data{
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    NSDictionary *resultDic = [[dic objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:0];
    for (NSString *key in _carStatuKey) {
        NSLog(@"value:%@",resultDic[key]);
        [_carStatuValue addObject:resultDic[key]];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _carStatuName.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CarStatuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CarStatuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.statuNameLabel.text = _carStatuName[indexPath.row];
    if (_carStatuValue.count  == 0) {
        cell.statuValueLabel.text = @"null";
    } else {
        cell.statuValueLabel.text = _carStatuValue[indexPath.row];//set value here will crash.
    }

    return cell;
}
@end
```

#### this is the table cell code, the crash log has many information about the Autolayout Constraint.

```
#import "CarStatuCell.h"
#include <Masonry.h>

@implementation CarStatuCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self initSubViews];
        [self setLayout];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initSubViews {
    _statuNameLabel = [UILabel new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_statuNameLabel];
    _statuValueLabel = [UILabel new];
    _statuValueLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _statuValueLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    _statuValueLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    _statuValueLabel.text = @"Null";
    [self.contentView addSubview:_statuValueLabel];
}

- (void)setLayout {
    [_statuNameLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(_statuNameLabel.superview.mas_left).with.offset(50);
        make.centerY.equalTo(_statuNameLabel.superview.mas_centerY);
    }];
    [_statuValueLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.equalTo(_statuValueLabel.superview.mas_right).with.offset(-50);
        make.centerY.equalTo(_statuValueLabel.superview.mas_centerY);
    }];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}

@end
```

#### the crash log :

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000a1605
2016-07-08 10:34:19.660 ChangHongYema[4216:239738] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000a1605'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062b8d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001059a6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062c1d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106207cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062078a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010469c8f6 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 84
6   UIKit                               0x000000010469c747 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 76
7   UIKit                               0x00000001046a140d -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 173
8   UIKit                               0x00000001046a14e4 -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 72
9   UIKit                               0x0000000104d1808b -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 35
10  UIKit                               0x0000000104d17d57 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 619
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104d20e93 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 224
12  UIKit                               0x00000001046a12c6 -[UILabel updateConstraints] + 256
13  UIKit                               0x0000000104d201be -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 550
14  UIKit                               0x0000000104d20489 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 198
15  UIKit                               0x0000000104d200cd -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 309
16  Foundation                          0x00000001039253d3 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
17  UIKit                               0x0000000104d1fadb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
18  UIKit                               0x0000000104d2045d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 154
19  UIKit                               0x0000000104d200cd -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 309
20  UIKit                               0x0000000104d20489 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 198
21  UIKit                               0x0000000104d20ac1 __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 98
22  UIKit                               0x0000000104d1fae4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 67
23  UIKit                               0x0000000104d2061e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 254
24  UIKit                               0x0000000104d21333 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 272
25  UIKit                               0x00000001044d5a96 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 159
26  UIKit                               0x00000001044e59a9 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 744
27  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109268c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
28  QuartzCore                          0x000000010925d08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
29  QuartzCore                          0x000000010925cf0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
30  QuartzCore                          0x00000001092513c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
31  QuartzCore                          0x000000010927f086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
32  UIKit                               0x000000010442572e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7135
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061de301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061d422c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061d36e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061d30f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
37  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010912bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
38  UIKit                               0x000000010442af09 UIApplicationMain + 171
39  ChangHongYema                       0x00000001030455df main + 111
40  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010702492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: it crashes because "_carStatuValue[indexPath.row]" is returning something of type "NFCNumber " rather than a string value.
Use [NSString stringWithFormat:] to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your cellforRow() method with following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CarStatuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CarStatuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.statuNameLabel.text = _carStatuName[indexPath.row];
    if (_carStatuValue.count  == 0) {
        cell.statuValueLabel.text = @"null";
    } else {
        cell.statuValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",_carStatuValue[indexPath.row]];//set value here will crash.
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning directly the value to a text.

in your cellForRow you can do something like:

```
id data = _carStatuName[indexPath.row];

// since the error seems that your data is a number type
 if([data isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    if(_carStatuValue.count == 0){
       cell.statuValueLabel.text = @"null"
     }
    else{
       cell.statuValueLabel.text = [data stringValue]; // use the NSNumber string value
    }
  }
  else{
  // pre-empt the crash
   cell.statuValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];  // will output whatever the data is. technically this shouldn't happen if you are sure all your data will be an NSNumber type
 }
```